# How to Select one of the repeated values in a column by groups

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

So I have this table:

[image: table t1 i am querrying from]

I am trying to produce a column that will look like this (containing the computed results)

[image: table to be produced]

I tried this query by it gives an error

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Amount) AS TAmnt, 
ProductPrice-SUM(Amount) AS OutB 
FROM t1
GROUP BY Name;
```

I tried this as well, but the results don't seem to be what i want

```
SELECT Name,SUM(Amount) AS TAmnt, 
SUM(ProductPrice)-SUM(Amount) AS OutB 
FROM t1 
GROUP BY Name;
```

Any help to see what I am missing?

Comment: Is `ProductPrice` always the same in every row for a name? You should normalize your data and put that in a separate table with one row per name.

Comment: Hi @Desdejei I have tried your code.
and I have not found any error.
please see [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c058e3/4)

Comment: Also, you appear to have no PRIMARY KEY, which may prove problematic in due course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ANY_VALUE()` to prevent the error. It will select the `ProductPrice` value from any row in the group.

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Amount) AS TAmnt, 
        ANY_VALUE(ProductPrice)-SUM(Amount) AS OutB 
FROM t1
GROUP BY Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try aggregating by name *and* product price:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    SUM(Amount) AS TAmnt, 
    ProductPrice - SUM(Amount) AS OutB 
FROM t1
GROUP BY
    Name,
    ProductPrice;
```

As mentioned by @Barmar, your current table is not normalized.  Given that a product has only one price, you should create a separate prices table, and store this information there.